# Derive string from const enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have the following in my constants file:

```
typedef enum
{
    AnimalTypeBear,
    AnimalTypeCamel,
    AnimalTypeCow,
    AnimalTypeCount

}
AnimalType;
```

If I declare an `AnimalType` variable somewhere in my code like following and set it to `AnimalTypeBear`:

```
AnimalType animalType = 0;
```

Is there away to somehow derive the string "Bear" from that `animalType` variable or just in general to access the string of its corresponding constant type (in this case `AnimalTypeBear`).

Comment: Yes: create an array of strings, index into the array using the members of the `enum`.

Comment: Yeah I know trying to avoid writing extra code, wondering if there is someway to access the string of the constant name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are constant expressions like #define. Enums at compile time will be "translated" into the code as constants (while #define will be evaluated before compilation). So basically it is not possible to reference the enum string in this way.

As suggested by others you can use a string array.

Comment: Thx! Alternatively you can use NSDictionary too which has key-value pairs which you might find useful to store the type (key) and the string (value). NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"BEAR",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Camel", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],..... nil];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without code in (Objective-)C. If you want to be able to use actual enumeration literals as strings in your code, or during I/O, with language support then you need to use a language with enumeration type support such as Pascal or Ada.

If you are keen to have this and don't mind work as long as it is reusable then you need to learn about reading the symbol tables structures from a binary and make sure that the information is not stripped from your application. You'll see the debugger can show the correct literals, also if you use Xcode's "Product > Generate Output > Assembly File" menu item you'll see the literals are in there as strings. It will be a lot of work for you, but would be reusable once done.

After that give up and write some code - a simple static array of labels and an index operation. Yes, it's a maintenance headache if you ever change your enumeration.

Alternatively you can write some different code, say in Ruby... Xcode supports adding your own file "types" and running scripts to (pre-)process them. So you could define, say, a file type ".enum" and use a Ruby script to convert that into a C enumeration definition and code to provide the strings. Apple has examples of using Ruby to pre-process files in this way. Once you have your script Xcode will do the rest, on each compilation it will run your script to convert your ".enum" into ".m" (or ".c") and the compile the result. This approach is usually best though for files which contain only one thing, e.g. localised string file processing, you don't usually write your enum declarations in their own files.